# adding a number to the computer's time

Tags: c

This is a program that prints the current time. how do i add numbers to the time printed. Example: the output of the program is **15:35**. how do i make it print **16:35**? if this isn't possible; i would like to know if they are any other methods i can use. thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char hc1,hc2,mc1,mc2;
    int hi1,hi2,mi1,mi2,hour,minute;
    system("echo %time% >time.txt");
    fp=fopen("time.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
       exit(1) ;
    hc1=fgetc(fp);
    hc2=fgetc(fp);
    fgetc(fp);
    mc1=fgetc(fp);
    mc2=fgetc(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    remove("time.txt");
    hi1=hc1;
    hi2=hc2;
    mi1=mc1;
    mi2=mc2;
    hi1-=48;
    hi2-=48;
    mi1-=48;
    mi2-=48;
    hour=hi1*10+hi2;
    minute=mi1*10+mi2;
    printf("the Current time is %d:%d\n",hour,minute);
}
```

Comment: Well, obviously, you would do `hour += 1;` before the `printf`, but you would need to account for the situation where `hour` is already `23` and roll to `0`. Like `hour = 23 ? 0 :  hour + 1;`

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add integers directly to your `hour` or `minute` variables similar to the two different ways here:

```
hour += 1;

hour = hour + 1;
```

Or do the literal addition in your `printf,

```
printf("the Current time is %d:%d\n",hour + 1,minute);
```

As David commented below, be mindful of pushing the hour or minute past 23 or 59, respectively.

Comment: What if hour is `23`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you, I added your comment to the answer.

Comment: You could replace your `hour + 1` with `(hour = 23 ? 0 : hour + 1)` and let the ternary do the work for you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I could. Or you could write your own answer at this point instead of hijacking mine lol. Your first comment was very wise; your second is a little advanced judging by the OP's question and its trivial solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing an application for getting current system time and performing arithmetic operation on it, a better way is to use the timeval struct in C.

It is present in the `"sys/time.h"` header and stores the time in both seconds and microseconds format. Also, it has got the `gettimeofday()` function to get current system time.

Following are the links for your reference:

1. [`Timeval struct`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/systime.h.html)
2. [`gettimeofday() function`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)

**NOTE:** Some of the functions used with this struct are not portable and may work only on Linux based systems.

Answer (score 0):

check this simple function

```
void AddTime(int& currentH, int& currentM, int& currentS, int addH, int addM, int addS)
{
    int extraM=(currentS+addS)/60;
    currentS=(currentS+addS)%60;
    int extraH=(currentM+addM+extraM)/60;
    currentM=(currentM+addM+extraM)%60;
    int extraD=(currentH+addH+extraH)/24;
    currentH=(currentH+addH+extraH)%24;
}
```